# angularjs: how does $index work in ng-repeat ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

consider the following table :

```
 <tbody data-ng-repeat="job in jobs">
    <tr>
        <td>{{job.fileName}}</td>  
        <td>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="deleteJob($index);"><i class="icon-delete"></i>&nbsp; delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

if I delete a job, the row id is passed to the function and it works just fine.

```
 scope.deleteJob = function (id) {
                scope.jobs.splice(id, 1);
            }
```

However if I change `deleteJob($index)` to `deleteJob({{$index}})` then, the index is still passed to the function, however if I delete row 1, the index of row 2 remains 2 and it is not updated.

How come ? What's the difference between the two approaches ?

Comment: Can you setup a plunker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because when you use `$index` it's a variable but when you use `{{$index}}` value used instead of variable.

If you check the DOM you will see that in the first `case($index)` you still see `$index` in DOM, but when you use `{{$index}}` you will see 0,1,2... in the DOM.

If you use `{{index}}`, when array is changed your DOM will still have have `deleteJob(0),deleteJob(2)` ... and so on - missing the deleted indices.

if you use `$index` your DOM will have `$index`, which is a variable that represents actual current index.

Answer (score 1):

I think `{{$index}}` is wrong aproach and valid usage of iterator offset of the repeated element must be `$index`.

`$index` is **iterator** and after delete one of items should be updated respectively.

When we write `{{$index}}` means - show current value stored in iterator.

Like in other languages, Java for example, if we run in loop over list (like `ng-repeat`) we can only use iterator to remove Item to prevent index issues

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/602/)</kbd>